# Clarification on Term Order of an Infinitesimal

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I've seen several questions posted on this, namely

1. [What is the order of an infinitesimal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466629/what-is-the-order-of-an-infinitesimal)
2. [Determine the order of an infinitesimal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934196/determine-the-order-of-an-infinitesimal)

I'm asking this question because I've seen it pop up in variational calculus and want to make sure the answers in the above posts apply.

e.g. Gelfand & Fomin's *Calculus of Variations* states (Section 3.2, pg. 11), for

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta J[h] &= J[y+h] - J[y] \\
&=\varphi [h] + \epsilon \lVert h \rVert,
\end{align}
$$

that *"the linear functional $\varphi [h]$ which differs from $\Delta J[h]$ **by an infinitesimal of order higher than 1 relative to $\lVert h \rVert$**, is called the [first] variation of $J[y]$ and is denoted by $\delta J[h]$*".

This kind of terminology appears more than once.

**Question**

Is the *order* of an infinitesimal, $\epsilon$, its integer power, $n$, such that

$$
\epsilon^n
$$

is an *nth-order infinitesimal*, with the only difference between orders of infinitesimals being how fast they converge to $0$?

*(This definition being purely due to Cauchy, explained in his text, the English annotated version of which is given here:*

http://users.uoa.gr/~spapast/TomeasDidaktikhs/Caychy/CauchyCoursdAnalyseAnAnnotatedTranslationSourcesandStudiesintheHistoryofMathematicsandPhysicalSciences.pdf))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the order of an infinitesimal is its integer power. The rate at which in converges to 0 is proportional to its order.